# Python 2-D Histogram with Discrete Colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have the following code that plots points and then plots a histogram:

```
# Produce a number of points in x-y from 1 distribution. 
mean = [3,4]
cov = [[3,1],[1,3]] 
x,y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean,cov,1000).T
plt.plot(x,y,'x'); plt.axis('equal'); plt.show()
Z = np.array([x,y])

# Produce 2D histogram projection
H,xedges,yedges = np.histogram2d(x,y,10,normed=False)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(xedges,yedges)
plt.imshow(H)
plt.grid(True)
```

I just want the histogram on imshow() to be blockier instead of so fuzzy so the density at each square bin is clearer. I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply set the interpolation method that `imshow` uses:

```
plt.imshow(H, interpolation = 'none')
```

Here's [an example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/image_interp.html) showing different interpolation methods, and [the docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) list all implemented methods.

Answer (score 3):

So, your initial code would look like this

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

```
# Produce a number of points in x-y from 1 distribution. 
mean = [3,4]
cov = [[3,1],[1,3]] 
x,y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean,cov,1000).T
plt.plot(x,y,'x'); plt.axis('equal'); plt.show()
Z = np.array([x,y])

# Produce 2D histogram projection
H,xedges,yedges = np.histogram2d(x,y,10,normed=False)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(xedges,yedges)
plt.imshow(H)
plt.grid(True)
```

[image]

[image]

And you want something like this if I understand "blockier" correctly!?

```
plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=40)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]